# Measure execution time in CPU cycles?

Tags: python, time, operating-system

My laptop spent 1.3 seconds to complete the process posted below.
The same code ran on another machine and the timing was different: 2.1 seconds. This is because another machine runs on different Operation System, it has different CPU, memory and etc.

I wonder if instead of timing the process in seconds there would be a way to measure CPU cycles it took for the computer to complete a given process. So if the same code is run on different machines the measurements taken would always result the same number, and the result would be something like: `it took 10,000 CPU cycles for this process to complete`....

```
import time
def run():
    for i in range(10000000):
        0+0
start_time = time.time()
run()
print 'processed in: %s sec'%(time.time() - start_time)
```

Comment: You might want to change your title to be more specfic. Because right now, it sounds like common duplicate.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

on linux systems you have `time` command, ie:

```
# time ls
/bin/ls ${=LS_OPTIONS}  0.00s user 0.00s system 68% cpu 0.003 total
```

Answer (score 2):

[hwcounter](https://github.com/paulsmith/hwcounter) could help.

```
from hwcounter import Timer, count, count_end
from time import sleep
from math import sqrt

start = count()
sqrt(144) / 12
elapsed = count_end() - start
print(f'elapsed cycles: {elapsed}')
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Windows?

Comment: This works in windows if you use the MSYS2 MinGw compiler to build the package. There is currently an issue in the repo, but it should be quite easy to fix for VS Windows builds as well.